# Enables markup to instantiate objects, call methods, and generate HTML

Tags: php, design-patterns, xml, template, dom

I created this package [PXP](https://github.com/hxtree/PXP/).

> PXP enables markup to instantiate objects, call methods, and generate
> HTML. It works similar to a server-side templating engine, but rather
> than enforcing braces it enables developers to use markup to build
> dynamic web pages.

I'm interested primary in feedback related to core implement below, which is implements a builder design pattern, is at the heart of the package, and nearing a 1.0 (although any feedback as an issues is welcomed).

What is done right?
What can be done to improve this package?

#### PXP/src/Page/PageDirector.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of the PXP package.
 *
 * (c) Matthew Heroux <matthewheroux@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace Pxp\Page;
use Pxp\Page\Builder\Builder;
/**
 * Class PageDirector
 * @package Pxp\Page
 */
class PageDirector
{
    /**
     * Calls Builder using parameters supplied
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param $parameters
     * @return object
     */
    public function build(Builder &$builder, $parameters): object
    {
        $builder->createObject($parameters);
        return $builder->getObject();
    }
}
```

#### PXP/src/Page/Builder/DynamicBuilder.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of the PXP package.
 *
 * (c) Matthew Heroux <matthewheroux@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
namespace Pxp\Page\Builder;
use Pxp\Page\Page as Page;
/**
 * Class DynamicBuilder
 * @package Pxp\Page\Builder
 */
class DynamicBuilder extends Builder
{
    private $page;
    /**
     * Creates Page object using parameters supplied
     *
     * @param $parameters
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function createObject(array $parameters): ?bool
    {
        if (!isset($parameters['filename'])) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->page = new Page($parameters['filename']);
        // instantiate dynamic elements
        if (is_array($parameters['handlers'])) {
            foreach ($parameters['handlers'] as $xpath_expression => $class_name) {
                $this->page->instantiateElement($xpath_expression, $class_name);
            }
        }
        // call hooks
        if (is_array($parameters['hooks'])) {
            foreach ($parameters['hooks'] as $name => $description) {
                $this->page->callHook($name, $description);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Gets Page object
     *
     * @return object|null
     */
    public function getObject(): ?object
    {
        return $this->page;
    }
}
```

#### PXP/src/Page/Page.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of the PXP package.
 *
 * (c) Matthew Heroux <matthewheroux@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Pxp\Page;

/**
 * Interface PageDefaultInterface
 * @package Pxp\Page
 */
interface PageDefaultInterface
{
    public function loadByPath(string $filepath): void;

    public function __toString(): string;

    public function callHook(string $hook_name, string $options = null): bool;

    public function instantiateElement(string $xpath_expression, string $class_name): bool;

    public function replaceElement(\DOMElement &$element, string $new_xml): void;

    public function query($query);
}

/**
 * Class Page
 *
 * Features a DOM loaded from a HTML/XML document that is modified during runtime
 *
 * @package Pxp\Page
 */
class Page implements PageDefaultInterface
{

    // Document Object Model (DOM)
    public $dom;

    // DOM XPath Query object
    public $xpath;

    // instantiated DynamicElements
    public $element_objects;

    // name of function called to load DynamicElement Args by ID
    public $arg_load_function;

    // DomDocument object setting to preserve white space
    public $preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    // DomDocument  format output option
    public $formatOutput = true;

    // DomDocument strict error checking setting
    public $strictErrorChecking = false;

    // validate DOM on Parse
    public $validateOnParse = false;

    // DomDocument encoding
    public $encoding = 'UTF-8';

    // registered includes added during output
    public $includes = [
        'js' => [],
        'css' => []
    ];

    // entities are required to avoid server side DOM parse errors
    public $entities = [
        'nbsp' => '&#160;',
        'copy' => '&#169;',
        'reg' => '&#174;',
        'trade' => '&#8482;',
        'mdash' => '&#8212;'
    ];

    // DynamicElement placeholder ID attribute
    private $element_index_attribute = '_pxp_ref';

    // DomDocument LibXML debug
    private $libxml_debug = false;

    /**
     * Page constructor
     *
     * @param null $filename
     */
    public function __construct($filename = null)
    {

        // create a document object model
        $this->dom = new \DomDocument();

        // objects containing elements
        $this->element_objects = new \SplObjectStorage();

        // surpress xml parse errors unless debugging
        if (!$this->libxml_debug) {
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        }

        if ($filename != null) {
            $this->loadByPath($filename);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom load page wrapper for server side HTML5 entity support
     *
     * @param string $filepath
     */
    public function loadByPath(string $filepath): void
    {
        if (filter_var($filepath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            // if existing website
            $source = file_get_contents($filepath);
            $this->dom->loadHTML($source);
        } else {
            // entities are automatically removed before sending to client
            $entity = '';
            foreach ($this->entities as $key => $value) {
                $entity .= '<!ENTITY ' . $key . ' "' . $value . '">' . PHP_EOL;
            }

            // deliberately build out doc-type and grab file contents
            // using alternative loadHTMLFile removes HTML entities (&copy; etc.)
            $source = '<!DOCTYPE html [' . $entity . ']> ';
            $source .= file_get_contents($filepath);
            $this->dom->loadXML($source);
        }



        // create document iterator
        $this->xpath = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);
    }

    /**
     * Calls single method to each instantiated DynamicElement
     *
     * @param string $hook_name
     * @param string|NULL $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function callHook(string $hook_name, string $options = null): bool
    {
        // iterate through elements
        foreach ($this->element_objects as $element) {

            // skip if element does not feature hook
            if (!method_exists($element, $hook_name)) {
                continue;
            }

            // on render
            if ($options == 'RETURN_CALL') {
                $query = '//*[@' . $this->element_index_attribute . '="' . $element->placeholder_id . '"]';

                foreach ($this->query($query) as $replace_element) {
                    $new_xml = $element->__toString();

                    $this->replaceElement($replace_element, $new_xml);
                    continue;
                }
            } else {

                // call element method
                call_user_func([
                    $element,
                    $hook_name
                ]);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * XPath query for DOM
     *
     * @param $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function query($query)
    {
        return $this->xpath->query($query);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces element contents
     *
     * @param \DOMElement $element
     * @param string $new_xml
     */
    public function replaceElement(\DOMElement &$element, string $new_xml): void
    {

        // create a blank document fragment
        $fragment = $this->dom->createDocumentFragment();
        $fragment->appendXML($new_xml);

        // replace parent nodes child element with new fragement
        $element->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $element);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates dynamic elements found during xpath query
     *
     * @param string $xpath_expression
     * @param string $class_name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function instantiateElement(string $xpath_expression, string $class_name): bool
    {
        // if class does not exist replace element with informative comment
        // iterate through handler's expression searching for applicable elements
        foreach ($this->query($xpath_expression) as $element) {

            // skip if placeholder already assigned
            if ($element->hasAttribute($this->element_index_attribute)) {
                continue;
            }

            // resolve class name
            $element_class_name = $class_name;
            if ($element->hasAttribute('name')) {
                $element_name = $element->getAttribute('name');
                $element_class_name = str_replace('{name}', $element_name, $class_name);
            }

            // if class does not exist
            if (!class_exists($element_class_name)) {
                $this->replaceElement($element, '<!-- Handler "' . $element_class_name . '" Not Found -->');
                continue;
            }

            // get xml from element
            $xml = $this->getXml($element);

            // get args from element
            $args = $this->getArgs($element);

            // instantiate element
            $element_object = new $element_class_name($xml, $args);

            // object not instantiated
            if (!is_object($element_object)) {
                $this->replaceElement($element, '<!-- Handler "' . $element_class_name . '" Error -->');
                continue;
            }

            // set element object placeholder
            $element->setAttribute($this->element_index_attribute, $element_object->placeholder_id);

            // store object
            $this->element_objects->attach($element_object);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get element's innerXML
     *
     * @param \DOMElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    private function getXml(\DOMElement $element): string
    {
        $xml = '';

        $children = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $xml .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Get element's ARGs
     *
     * @param \DOMElement $element
     * @return array
     */
    private function getArgs(\DOMElement &$element): array
    {
        $args = [];

        // get attributes
        if ($element->hasAttributes()) {
            foreach ($element->attributes as $name => $attribute) {
                $args[$name] = $attribute->value;
            }
        }

        // get child args
        $objects = $element->getElementsByTagName('arg');
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $name = $object->getAttribute('name');
            $value = $object->nodeValue;
            $args[$name] = $value;
        }

        // use element id attribute to load args
        if ($element->hasAttribute('id')) {
            $element_id = $element->getAttribute('id');

            // allow director to specify function to load args from based on id
            if (function_exists($this->arg_load_function)) {
                $args_loaded = call_user_func($this->arg_load_function, $element_id);

                // merge args
                $args = array_merge($args_loaded, $args);
            }
        }

        return $args;
    }

    /**
     * Returns DomDocument as HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->dom->saveHTML();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your question. I find it hard to understand [what your code does an how it can be used](https://pxp.readthedocs.io/en/latest). It is no good having a library that no one can use because they can't understand it. As a programmer, not a user, I would also like to know why you chose this structure. What is the purpose of a `PageDirector`, `PageBuilder`, `Page`, etc? I understand that you have concentrated your efforts on the technical implementation, but we can only review code if we can understand the ideas and concepts behind it.

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware. You are 100% correct! The docs/readme are scribbles (I was experimenting with PHP phpdocumentor doing reST and not there yet, will manually write ASAP); please try the examples, they should make sense. The design pattern was chosen to separate the construction of the complex page objects from its representation so that different types of pages could be built, e.g. static for (WYSIWYG), dynamic (for rendering to client), search index (to exclude dynamic objects marked), etc.

Comment: I did have a look at the examples, before I wrote the comment above. It seems your aim is to make it easier for programmers to write dynamic pages in HTML. However, to do so, they also need to write the matching PHP code, which, in my eyes, only complicates things. I agree that combining HTML and PHP in one file can be ugly, but it does keep things together. As for your implementation, I already indicated that I think you purely concentrated on the technology, and didn't think about the persons who are supposedly going to use it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the package adheres to the UNIX philosophy. Yes, the average Jane would be more likely to use a package that will include this package, which would feature built in DynamicElements, TinyMCE, etc. Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that this code was posted nearly two years ago and the code in the repository has changed immensely, I shall aim to provide feedback on the code as is.

## Well-documented code

This code is very well documented with docblocks, and makes great use of return type declarations (including nullable).

## Some comments redundant

The comments within methods are nice though some are not necessary and in fact redundant because the code is so readable- e.g.:

> ```
> // get xml from element
> $xml = $this->getXml($element);
>
> // get args from element
> $args = $this->getArgs($element);
> ```

## Single-use variables can be eliminated

There are a few variables that are only used once after being assigned so those can likely be simplified- e.g. in method `Page::getXml()` -

> ```
> $children = $element->childNodes;
> foreach ($children as $child) {
>     $xml .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
> }
> ```

`$children` can be eliminated by updating the `foreach`:

```
foreach ($element->childNodes as $child) {
    $xml .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
}
```

Similarly in `Page:: getArgs()` the second `foreach` loop declares `$name` and `$value`:

> ```
> foreach ($objects as $object) {
>     $name = $object->getAttribute('name');
>     $value = $object->nodeValue;
>     $args[$name] = $value;
> }
> ```

This could be simplified to :

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $args[$object->getAttribute('name')] = $object->nodeValue;
}
```